# What do "barely one in three" and "will bother" mean in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What do "will bother" and "barely one in three" mean in this context?

> **Barely one in three will bother** to cast a ballot on February 26th.
>   *(from Longman)*

I was looking out to check meaning of "cast a ballot" that is to vote in an election when I saw this difficult example!

Comment: Basically, it means "less than 1/3 of people who had the right to vote would go out to 'cast a ballot'".

Answer (score 1):

> Barely one in three will bother to cast a ballot on Feb 26.

The word *[bother](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/BOTHERED)* means to *take the trouble to do something; concern oneself*. In other words to make some efforts or even to consider that matter to do.

The sentence means that hardly one in three will be interested (taking pain/making efforts) to cast a vote in that election.

So the chances are very few people will actually cast a ballot (a prediction). And as stated in comment less than one third would actually vote as predicted.

Comment: If you will address OP's question about 'one in three' (Damkerng's comment is all that's really needed) I'll be happy to upvote this.